# Is visiting the Hidden Wiki legal without visiting any illegal links presented on this site?

Tags: internet

Is visiting [the Hidden Wiki](http://zqktlwi4fecvo6ri.onion/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) legal if you do not visit any illegal links presented on this site? For example, for education purposes?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Yes, it does, thank you. Why did you edit the question like this by the way?

Comment: Because your onion link only works for those who have their DNS set up that way; most do not.